# workstation on domain won't accept any domain credentials for access

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, domain

Someone added a windows 7 workstation to this windows 2003 domain. They can login locally and say they are on the domain, and have mapped drive resources.

Trying to connect with psexec or anything else I have tried will not accept either the username/password combination or any domain administrator/password combination.

The workstation does not show in the AD but is listed in dns in the reverse lookup zone but not forward lookup zone and pinging resolves to the correct ip. DHCP shows a lease for a couple more weeks.

I have no idea what was done (because no one admits anything) it is a small network 25 machines.

Netdom won't work because I can't provide an accepted user/password combination. No one there has a clue enough to even walk them through anything. So I have to try remotely resolving this.

Any idea what to try next? Or what else I might try. I am a volunteer IT guy on this.

Comment: Add the workstation to the AD.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like the computer was actually joined to the domain.

Comment: I don't really think this computer was added to the domain, yet it shows with the domain appended in dns. But how to add it remotely now is what I need to do

Answer (score 2):

Right click my computer and click properties. At the bottom it should say what domain it is connected to.

If it doesn't show up in AD users and computers then it isn't really on the domain. Remove it and add it again.

Mapped network drives doesn't mean they are on the domain. It may just have domain credentials saved for the drive.

Comment: I should have made it clearer, I am working remotely. How do you remove it when it accepts no login credentials?

Comment: Ah.  If you are working remotely you'll either need to guide the user through doing it (good luck!) or use something like TeamViewer to access the system remotely.

Comment: yeah I am afraid this is what has to happen. The person who put the machine on the network is their new network admin

Comment: My usual strategy in this situation is to get them to load TeamViewer on their computer (which can take 20 minutes to walk a clueless user through, but can be done).  From there install logmein or enable remote desktop so I can keep remote access.  Then start troubleshooting.

Comment: Appreciated the note regarding mapped drives not indicating they are on the domain.